# Classpath set but java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError com/google/protobuf/MessageOrBuilder error?

Tags: java, linux, classpath, protocol-buffers

I am trying to run a java program that uses protobuf.jar, but I keep getting this error.

I have set my classpath variable in linux so that:

```
 CLASSPATH=/home/.../src/PlaceServer.class:/home/.../src/protobuf.jar:/home/.../src
 export CLASSPATH
```

But then when I run my program in the command line after reading in the jar.

```
 java PServer
```

I get this:

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/protobuf/MessageOrBuilder
```

However when I run another program that also reads the same jar, this one called BServer

```
 java BServer
```

It works fine, and correctly as I want it. I even tried running under these commands instead

```
 java -cp .protobuf.jar PServer
```

And it still did not work for PServer.

However, if I run the same programs on my Macbook from the command line (also in Eclipse in either OS) I do not get this Exception and it all works fine.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The error indicates that `PServer` uses protobufs but Java is not finding `protobuf.jar` correctly. I don't see any obvious problem in your classpath specification, though. Are you sure you specified the path to `protobuf.jar` correctly? Maybe `BServer` works fine because it simply doesn't use protobufs? Maybe it works on mac because the files are in different locations there, or because `protobuf.jar` is already installed in some common location? Need more info to say.

Comment: PS. It's kind of crazy to learn that there are now professors forcing their students to use my code! I hope you don't end up hating it the way I hated every book I was made to read in literature classes! :)

Comment: I think I figured it out, it was weird and for some reason, Java read the CLASSPATH differently on different machines so I was forced to identify it more explicitly. In regards to protobuf, it was really cool, it was refreshing to learn something new in class!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things to check to get rid of this error:

- Verify that all required Java classes are included in the application’s classpath. The most common mistake is not to include all the necessary classes, before starting to execute a Java application that has dependencies on some external libraries.
- The classpath of the application is correct, but the Classpath environment variable is overridden before the application’s execution

When you run the application in Eclipse, the IDE resolves this by using the .classpath file inside the project folder.  When you build an application (create the jar), you could accidentally omit this class, or change its location.

What you need to do is to first open the jar, and make sure that the class in question is in fact inside the jar, in the same path. Then, go through the list above.

Comment: I checked and the MessageOrBuilder.class does exist in the 'protobuf.jar' that I'm using in my application. So you're saying that I should check against either of the two bullet points you've stated?

Comment: If that class is supposed to be in that jar, you must rebuild the jar correctly so it is where it is supposed to be. Alternatively, you can compile that class by itself and manually add it to the jar. I am curious, how did you build the jar in the first place? You should consider reviewing the Java tutorial on [Creating a JAR File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html).

Comment: Well this is a project for class, so I used the jar that my professor supplied us with. I didn't compile the protobuf.jar myself I will try to do that.

Comment: @hfontanez This is wrong: "Also, the entries are supposed to be separated by semicolon ';', not colon ':'." -- That is only true on Windows. Nice-kun appears to be on Unix.

Comment: I stand corrected.  Thanks Kenton Varda. You are correct. The OP posted (and I overlooked) "I have set my classpath variable in Linux..."