# Error while reading contents of file - mapreduce

Tags: caching, hadoop, nullpointerexception, mapreduce

Reading contents of a file which has been passed as argument to the program and displaying it in the console is part of my program. When I read to read the contents of my file, I am getting error. When I omit the setup() and run my program,it is working fine. But I want to display the contents of the file. Below is my code.

```
package search;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.text.Format;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.URI;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;



public class search {



    public static class SearchMapper extends
            Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
        // Map code goes here.
        private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
        private Text word = new Text();

        public void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
            Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
            java.net.URI[] localPaths = context.getCacheFiles();
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            try {
                File file = new File(localPaths[0]);
                reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


        } 

        public void map (LongWritable Key, Text value,Context context )throws IOException,InterruptedException{

            String txt= value.toString();

                word = context.getCurrentValue();
                context.getCurrentKey();
                word.set(txt);
                context.write(word, one);

    }
    }

    public static class SearchReducer extends
            Reducer<Text, IntWritable,  Text, IntWritable> {
        // Reduce code goes here.

         private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();
            public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
             Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
                int sum = 0;
                for (IntWritable val : values) {
                   sum += val.get();
               }
               result.set(sum);
                context.write(key,result);
            }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args)
                .getRemainingArgs();
        if (otherArgs.length != 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: SearchCounter <in> <out>");
            System.exit(2);
        }

        Job job = Job.getInstance(new Configuration());
        job.addCacheFile(new Path("/Users/praveen/input/").toUri());
        job =new Job(conf);

        job.setJarByClass(search.class);
        job.setMapperClass(SearchMapper.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(SearchReducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(SearchReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[1]));
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
    }
```

I am getting the below error:

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:403)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at search.search$SearchMapper.setup(search.java:59)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:763)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:339)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:235)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
2015-06-06 17:00:42,907 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1338)) - Job job_local1148982887_0001 running in uber mode : false
2015-06-06 17:00:42,909 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1345)) -  map 0% reduce 0%
2015-06-06 17:00:42,912 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1358)) - Job job_local1148982887_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: NA
2015-06-06 17:00:42,921 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1363)) - Counters: 0
```

please point out what is wrong here.

Comment: Well setup is the place where the config stuff happens. At which line is the null pointer happening. Please mention that. Its line 59 as per exception, but what is in that line :)

Comment: @ramzy - line 59 is reader.close()

Answer (score 0):

Why do you re-create the Job after adding the cache file to it? Try to remove this line:

> ```
>     job =new Job(conf);
> ```

Comment: When I removed that line, I am getting the below error.

Comment: When I removed that line, I am getting the below error.'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/protobuf/MessageOrBuilder
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
 at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:1659)
 at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1624)
 ...

Comment: Not sure it will fix the pb, but there are missing @override annotations in your mapper/reducer classes

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26834465/classpath-set-but-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-protobuf-messageorbu) for the exception. There is that jar missing. Along with this, try to debug and see how the flow moved and which things are causing error.